# Изменение значений без перезагрузки страницы и кликов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите кто может.

Есть перемменая с числом `$zifre = "10";` и есть два инпута

```
<input type="text" value="" name="input_1" />
<input type="text" value="" name="input_2" />
```

Нужно чтобы когда в первый инпут `name="input_1"` вводиш число то она отнималось от занчания перемменой `$zifre` и результат выводился во второй инпут `name="input_2"`.

Как все это сделать без перезагрузки страницы и нажатий по кнопкам?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var inp1 = $('input[name="input_1"]');
  var inp2 = $('input[name="input_2"]'),
      res;
  $(document).on('input', 'input[name="input_1"]', function(){
    res = parseInt(zifre) - parseInt(inp1.val());
    $('input[name="input_2"]').val(res);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 var zifre = 10;// в вашем случае - <?=$zifre=?>
</script>
<input type="text" value="" name="input_1" />
<input type="text" value="" name="input_2" />
```

Comment: В var zifre подставил свое значение var zifre = <? echo "$zifre"; ?>;
Но  как сделать чтобы считало сразу, без кликов мишкой?

Comment: Уже разобрался, просто  заменил change на input
Спасибо за помощь